# How to set label to StatelessAjaxSubmitLink?

Tags: label, wicket, wicketstuff

I need to use wicketstuff's StatelessAjaxSubmitLink but I can't find any way to customize the default label ("Submit Query"). The class does not inherit a setLabel() method. Is there a way how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `setBody`.

UPDATE

If you are using your component with a HTML tag `<input type="submit"/>` , than you should use `value` attribute to set you desired label. In Wicket use `AttributeAppender`:

> yourLink.add(AttributeAppender.append("value", "foo bar"));

See https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_modifing_tag_attributes

Comment: I tried to use it, but I get  a runtime error, possibly because I am trying to use it with input?
`Expected close tag for '<input wicket:id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn get-started-button">' Possible attempt to embed component(s) '<input wicket:id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn get-started-button">' in the body of this component which discards its body`

Comment: I've updated the answer for you specific case. Check it out!